# Is there a way to see context data given to the template?

Tags: django, django-templates

usually there is a views or a url pattern that sends context to a tamplate. This is all fair and good when the code you are implementing is your own. But right now im finding myself implementing allauth and im not sure about the context "keys" (not sure if thats the right word, but i mean something like "user.is_authenticated") I can use in the template. One way of finding out which context objects are given to the template is to find the get_context_data function in the source code of the code that I am using. But is there a faster way to see the context given to the template?

regards

Comment: Ah, yes. I searched for the topic but couldnt quite find the right topic. Sorry, now this question exists twice. Is there a way to close this question? I'm quite new here.

Comment: Don't worry about it. I've closed it as a duplicate now.

Answer (score 1):

Are you in debug mode? one way can be to raise an error on the template (e.g. use a fake templatetag such as `{% fake %}`) and access local vars tab

[image]

Comment: `local vars tab` in what? The Dev Tools, or the/a Python debugger?